# Do two inline divs need to have floats?

Tags: html, css

I have two child divs that are inline at 50% each inside of a parent div. I am using `:after` on the parent to draw a `hr` under it with a 15px top and bottom margin.

The `hr` will not go under the parent div unless I float *one* of the child divs either left or right. If I float both of them, the `hr` renders somewhere in the middle of the parent div.

I've floated the left child div left and it renders fine, but prompts me to ask: Don't I need to float both child divs, or is it acceptable, or more correct to float both of them?

**EDIT:**

Notice how the fiddle shows the `hr` almost on top of the parent `.double` div.

http://jsfiddle.net/SatdL/

```
.single,
.double {
float:left;
width:100%
}

.single:after,
.double:after {
Content:"";
margin:15px 0;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border-bottom:1px solid #E2E2E2;
box-sizing:content-box;
display:block;
height:1px;
}

.double .small-left {
width:49%;
float:left;
display:inline-block;
padding-right:15px;
border-right:1px solid #E2E2E2;
vertical-align:top;
}

.double .small-right {
width:42%;
float:right;
border:none;
display:inline-block;
padding-left:15px;
vertical-align:top;
}


<div class="double">
  <div class="small-left">Test</div>
  <div class="small-right">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your current code in your question? Additionally, providing it in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) helps.

Comment: Sure, Mark. I'll add a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I am not following is this what you are trying to accomplish? [**Check This Out**](http://jsfiddle.net/asapmmeehan/SatdL/2/)

```
.small-left,
.small-right {
    width:48%;
    float:left;
    padding:0 1%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}

.small-left {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left:-1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could achieve what you are after without using ::after

However, a fix using that method is simply to add clear:both so that it wraps below the other content of that class.  You probably also don't need the height:1px;

```
.single:after,
.double:after {
Content:"";
clear:both;
border-bottom:1px solid #E2E2E2;
box-sizing:content-box;
display:block;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HH5s7/